# Cannot find module package.json with Electron + Strapi v4

Tags: node.js, electron, strapi

I am experiencing a problem creating a boilerplate with Electron and Strapi CMS, with the Strapi v4 only.
A similar boilerplate already exist for Strapi v3 at the following url https://github.com/afdallismen/electron-strapi-boilerplate and it works fine.

So I made some changes and I made a similar one with Strapi v4: https://github.com/AsoStrife/Strapi-V4-Electron-Boilerplate

Here my two main files:

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Strapi-V4-Electron-Boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application with Strapi v4",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "strapi-start": "strapi start",
    "strapi-develop": "strapi develop",
    "strapi-build": "strapi build",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-build": "electron-builder",
    "build": "strapi build && electron-builder"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "Strapi",
    "Boilerplate",
    "CMS"
  ],
  "author": "Andrea Corriga",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.3.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.3.0",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.3.2",
    "better-sqlite3": "7.4.6",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-is-packaged": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^19.0.8",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.5"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "23376639-3e73-4487-812b-a57332ff6859"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.x.x <=16.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  }
}
```

and `main.js`

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const Strapi = require('@strapi/strapi')
const isPackaged = require('electron-is-packaged')
const strapi = Strapi()

if (isPackaged) {
    const fs = require('fs')
    const path = require('path')
  
    const appPath = path.join(app.getPath('home'), app.getName())
  
    const requiredFolderPaths = {
        database: path.join(appPath, 'database'),
        public: path.join(appPath, 'public'),
        uploads: path.join(appPath, 'public', 'uploads'),
    }
  
    Object.values(requiredFolderPaths).forEach((folderPath) => {
        if (!fs.existsSync(folderPath)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(folderPath, { recursive: true });
        }
    })
}

process.env.NODE_ENV = isPackaged ? 'production' : 'development';
process.env.BROWSER = 'none';

function createWindow () {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })

    win.maximize()
    win.webContents.openDevTools()
    strapi
        .start()
        .then(() => {
            win.loadURL('http://localhost:1337/admin');
            //win.loadFile('index.html')
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err)
        })

        win.on('closed', () => {
            app.quit();
        })
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()

    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow()
        }
    })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})
```

So where's the problem?
If I run `npm run electron` it works perfectly, Electron opens correctly, with Strapi UI, a working DB and API accessible by localhost.
But if I run `npm run build` or `npm run electron-build` I generate a `Strapi-V4-Electron-Boilerplate.exe` but it doesn't work.

It gives me this error and I don't know how to debug. All dependencies are correct (I suppose, since with the `npm run electron` command everything works.

[image]

Has anyone experienced similar problems? Do you have any idea how to debug this problem to figure out what is not working?

**Update 05/08/2022 [DD/MM/YYYY]**

The solution is to change the strapi constructor

```
const strapi = Strapi({
    appDir: `${__dirname}/`,
})
```

In Strapi v4 the parameter is `appDir` instead of `dir` in v3.
Once the app is built, if you try to run the executable (eg.`.exe`) and the app crashes on startup you may need to copy and paste the `.env`file inside the folder where the executable is located.

So if your `.exe` is located on `./dist/win-unpacked` copy the `.env-example` into that folder and rename it in `.env`. This file follow the Strapi guideline. Check out strapi's documentation to learn more.